# Stored Procedures<-->Tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

where to find which stored procedures correlate with a table in SQL Server Management Studio 2016?

--I want to find which stored procedures use a specific table in SQL Server Management Studio. Is this clear?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: For `Postgresql`? You don't. SSMS is for SQL Server only.

Comment: What on earth do you mean??

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "functions correlate with a table". Functions can query from tables. You can get an overview of what tables are queried by a function by using `sys.sql_dependencies`.

Comment: That does, however, require the function to have been built with schema binding on though, @JeroenMostert. Hopefully, the user does..? :)

Comment: @Larnu: No, that's not required. `sql_dependencies` lists non-schema bound dependencies as well (`OBJECT_OR_COLUMN_REFERENCE_NON_SCHEMA_BOUND`, I just tested it to make sure). Of course, because of the lack of schema binding, it is possible for the references to go out of sync and be incorrect, but then you'd probably have a problem executing the function as well.

Answer (score 2):

At a complete and utter guess...:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname;
SET @TableName = N'YourTablename';

SELECT o.[name]
FROM sys.sql_modules sm
     JOIN sys.objects o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE sm.[definition] LIKE N'%' + @TableName + N'%'
  --AND o.type IN ('FN','IF','TF') --OP previously stated Function.
  AND o.type = 'P'; --They meant Stored Procedure.
```

Of course, if you have very generically named objects, (maybe `customer`) for a table's name, that is also the name of a column you'll get false positives.

Also, in case of further confusion for object types, you can find out the different ones by looking at the documentation: [`sys.objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Since the question has changed the answer should be adjusted. You can leave out the AND that will get you any stored proc, function, view, table, trigger,... where the SearchValue is used. Or adjust the AND to your specific needs

Comment: So it's Stored Procecure now, I see @GuidoG . Well it doesn't change the goal posts that much, but they are very different objects; seems to OP didn't know this. :)